# Bad Request 400 Curl Problem

Tags: php, api, curl, httpwebrequest, bad-request

It seems like im getting a problem when Im trying to send a request to a server in php. The http api request is something like this:

> https://www.quickbase.com/db/basddzvkb?act=API_DoQuery&ticket=6_bsdaaap8y_by5bx6_b_crji7wwewew3b9asd5zibmf8jh3bhsdsddvhruc9csquzdg9bzw4&apptoken=cgsb5xdwehusdaaagcjs222dz9&fmt=structured&query={'22'.ct.'test'}

I have the following part of my code in php where I believe the error is occuring:

```
else
    {
        $ch = curl_init($input);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        $this->input = $input;

    }

    $r = curl_exec($ch);

    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));


    if($return_xml) {
        $response = new SimpleXMLElement($r);
    }
```

This is what I get from the print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)) statement:

> [content_type] => text/html 
>    [http_code] => 400 
>    [header_size] => 129 
>    [request_size] => 251 
>    [filetime] => -1 
>    [ssl_verify_result] => 20 
>    [redirect_count] => 0 
>    [total_time] => 0.281 
>    [namelookup_time] => 0 
>    [connect_time] => 0.063 
>    [pretransfer_time] => 0.188 
>    [size_upload] => 0 
>    [size_download] => 20 
>    [speed_download] => 71 
>    [speed_upload] => 0 
>    [download_content_length] => 20 
>    [upload_content_length] => 0 
>    [starttransfer_time] => 0.281 
>    [redirect_time] => 0 
>    [certinfo] => Array ( )

Also as you can see that I commented out the curlopt_post, its because it was causing problems when I was doing a different api request. Im not sure what the solution can be and I have been looking at this problem for awhile now hopefully someone can help me thanks :)

Comment: Are you using urlencode to construct your url?

Comment: actually if I urlencode the $input it produces an error instead on my compiler.

Comment: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'

Comment: You don't want to do that in the entire URL. You only need to do it on values in the query string. The last part should be passed as `%7B'22'.ct.'test'%7D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datasage helped me come up with this answer, you basically have to add urlencode("{'22'.ct.'test'}"); to this part of the code and it will produce the correct output.